# Fatal error: Uncaught PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException: Got Http response code 403

Tags: paypal

I am trying to integrate PayPal checkout in Codeigniter, I have installed PayPal SDK using the composer but it not working.  Basically what I'm trying to do here is to include a PayPal smart checkout button, which after login redirects to my server where I created an order and execute. I don't know what wrong with this code as it looks like all ok here, but still getting an error.  Currently I am using my APP's sandbox ClientID and secret.

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require './vendor/autoload.php';


use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
use PayPal\Api\ExecutePayment;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;




class paymentController extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -  
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */


    public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();


            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->helper('html');
            $this->load->helper('email');
            $this->load->library('session');

            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->helper('cookie');
            $this->load->library('cart');




       }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('payment controller index function');
    }


    public function execute(){
        $apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
        new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
                    'AVIPqzQ05Njz9589zFa3bn_PcIC-k-rLp0p0JdCjcfot--WtdBu7gLRWbOHRkDhDCODk_tYIHKRG4SCa',     // ClientID
                    'EIus88X-MF7d0ZATg7XSek4JjAtA7WHBAHc3pe0xHRRRzk9_siHEua3wQlXmtQo2a-Xr5hMHS_Osl1eW'      // ClientSecret
                )
        );

        $paymentId = $_GET['paymentId'];
        $payment = payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);

        $execution = new PaymentExecution();
        $execution->setPayerId($_GET['PayerID']);

        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $amount = new Amount();
        $details = new Details();

        $details->setShipping(2.2)
            ->setTax(1.3)
            ->setSubtotal(17.50);

        $amount->setCurrency('USD');
        $amount->setTotal(21);
        $amount->setDetails($details);
        $transaction->setAmount($amount);

         $execution->addTransaction($transaction);

         $result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);
         print_r($result);




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question should provide a more full response log of the 403 message, including a PayPal-Debug-Id if available.

But reviewing your code, it appears you may need to add something like:

```
$apiContext->setConfig(
    array(
        'mode' => 'sandbox',
        'log.LogEnabled' => true,
        'log.FileName' => '../PayPal.log',
        'log.LogLevel' => 'DEBUG', // PLEASE USE `INFO` LEVEL FOR LOGGING IN LIVE ENVIRONMENTS
    )
```

Sample adapted from https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/bootstrap.php

Without such a context addition, it would appear your code is attempting to use the Sandbox ClientID and secret **in a default live mode**, which will never work, and hence result in an expected 4xx error.

---

Separately, I would recommend you switch from the v1/payments PayPal-PHP-SDK to an implementation that uses the newer v2/orders API for PHP: https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK